# AS3 : Create a responsive mxml resize bitmapimage which resizes according to browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a simple bitmap image 3px wide and 150px high included as the top banner in my layout.

```
<s:BitmapImage id="blueBanner" source="{this.bmpimg}" width="100%"/>
```

The rest of the content is centered below this.

When the page opens no matter the size of the browser window, the image always fills the width available.

I have a browser window resize handler that resets my main content below the banner to the center of the new window size and this works perfectly.

But no matter how many times the browser is resized, the BitmapImage will never stretch **wider** than the original window width.

I have tried every property and method of BitmapImage that I think could affect this in the resize handler but nothing I can find has any effect at all.

I cannot understand how it remembers the original stage width to begin with.

Its parent containers are all set to 100% width and there are no unusual skins or any other reference to this object in the whole project except in a function where it can be included in the layout or not, but this function is never called in this case.

Can anyone offer any clue as to why it won't stretch automatically?

Doug

Comment: And you've looked at ScaleMode ?

Comment: @NealDavis I agree, if stage.scaleMode is not set, the content scales automatically and resize handler never called (I think).

Comment: If you post a small sample app I could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Simple , just set the width to `screen.width` and you are good to go.

```
<s:BitmapImage id="blueBanner" source="{this.bmpimg}" width="{screen.width}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses. In fact I solved the problem by adding the BitmapImage line to the Application Skin. Once it's here **as well** as in the layout it works. I have no idea why it needs to be in both places, but once it's set up like this everything works correctly.

Setting ScaleMode makes no difference and setting screen.width either in the blueBanner tag or later in the resizeHandler (because not always available when the tag is run) also makes no difference in my layout.

Doug